# Output elapsed time since last message in Log4Net

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using log4net in c# console app, and I was wondering if it was possible to have each log entry include the elapsed time since the last log entry?

Right now, I am using `%-4timestamp` (which I believe is the milliseconds since the start of the log) so I can spin through the log later and calculate the difference between an entry and the previous entry.  I was hoping there was something I could use to get the elapsed time to appear in each log message though.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
To clarify the elapsed time, I mean the amount of time that has elapsed since the last time log4net has logged a message.

For example, if I have this log:

```
0    [main] INFO  MyApp  - Entering application.
36   [main] DEBUG Com.Foo.Bar  - Did it again!
51   [main] INFO  MyApp  - Exiting application.
```

Then the additional information I would like would be something like this:

```
0   (0)  [main] INFO  MyApp  - Entering application.
36  (36) [main] DEBUG Com.Foo.Bar  - Did it again!
51  (15) [main] INFO  MyApp  - Exiting application.
```

Where the extra value I added in between parenthesis is the elapsed time since the last log.

Comment: What do you mean by elapsed time, did you mean elapsed time between two different log events, or you mean the time spent for logging specific event?

Comment: I mean the elapsed time since log4net last logged a message.  I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: OK, why you need this (when you could have a logging time history, you can use it in your log parser).

Comment: I am using it during development to find the slow points.  What do you mean by log parser?  I currently have a quick Perl command line to find the difference, but is there another tool to do this?  I would rather have the number directly in the logs during development.

Comment: By parser I mean something like your own perl command, but I think there isn't such a capability in log4net but you can write it in your message text I mean before sending message for logging, add extra text in start of message to handle this (just should have a variable to keep track of logging time), also you could handle it with custom log file appender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just keep track of it and add it yourself?

Something like:

```
public static class LoggingWrapper
    {
        private static ILog logger;
        private DateTime timeOfLastLog;

        static LoggingWrapper()
        {
            logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
            logger.Info("Logger initialized");
            timeOfLastLog = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public static void Debug(string Message)
        {
            logger = LogManager.GetLogger("YourDebugLoggerName");
            TimeSpan differential = DateTime.Now - timeOfLastLog();
            logger.Debug(Message + "-----" + differential.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Obviously youd want to customize a bit, but this is the basic idea. I always use a wrapper class to do logging, just because it adds customization capabilities. For example, I use it to do custom exception logging like this:

```
public static void LogException(Exception ex)
{
    logger = LogManager.GetLogger("NHibernate.SQL");
    logger.Error(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.InnerException + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace, ex);
}
```

That way, when I want to log exception details, I can do something like:

```
try
{
    ThrowAnException();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    LoggingWrapper.LogException(ex);
}
```

instead of:

```
try
{
    ThrowAnException();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    LoggingWrapper.Error(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.InnerException + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

And that's just one example. There are quite a few other things that make this useful.

Comment: If log4net doesn't handle this natively, then I think this is the best option.  Thanks very much!

Comment: @BrianH You're welcome! And even if it *does* handle this natively (I doubt it does, but who knows), I think this is still the way you want to go. This way, you can also add custom logging methods. In a second, I'm going to edit the post with a couple of examples just to show you.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I was just looking for the same and disliked to wrap the logger. I think a much better way is to use a `PatternConverter`:

```
class DeltaPatternConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
{
    private DateTime _last = DateTime.MinValue;

    protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        int ms = 0;
        if (_last != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            ms = (int)Math.Round((now - _last).TotalMilliseconds, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
        }
        writer.Write("+" + ms);
        _last = now;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var layout = new PatternLayout("%7timestampms (%7deltams) [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline");
layout.AddConverter("delta", typeof(DeltaPatternConverter));
layout.ActivateOptions();
```

Or like this:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <converter>
        <name value="delta"></name>
        <type value="My.Cool.Project.DeltaPatternConverter"></type>
      </converter>
      <conversionPattern value="%7timestampms (%7deltams) [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

The String *delta* will be converted.